# removing CSV files once they are used using bash

Tags: bash, csv

I am currently working on several transformations starting from a CSV file (file1.csv).
Once the transformation is done, I export it to a new file (file2.csv).
 `>file2.csv`

I would like to remove then the first file (file1.csv) with bash code.

How can I do?

I could not find related information over here.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use pipes instead of temporary files, you do not need to remove anything.

Comment: @ceving, I know, but it's expected from my side to save each time in a file and then removing it. I've been using pipes until now.

Comment: In most cases it is beneficial to use the [EXIT trap](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-trap-command) to perform cleanup tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, that i completely understand your question, because you should find plenty information about what you're describing.

Just use:

```
rm /some-directory/file2.csv
```

Comment: yes, I think this is what I was asking about. ```rm /`pwd`/file2.csv``` would be right for setting the current directory as the directory where to remove from?

Comment: Correct, `rm /pwd/file2.csv` removes "file2.csv" from the directory "pwd".

Comment: You're missing the crucial `&&` between the 2 commands and so are going to wipe out your data if/when the first command fails. Don't use sudo for this - if you need sudo then the file you're trying to remove isn't one you should be trying to remove for an application like this. And no, you don't need ```rm /`pwd`/file2.csv``` to remove `file2.csv` from the current directory, just `rm file2.csv`,

Comment: @IñigoCatalánEchave a wild `\`pwd\`` is no good, you should double-quote it

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you should really be doing:

```
cmd file1.csv > file2.csv && rm file1.csv
```

where `cmd` is whatever command you're running.