# awk to save changes in csv

Tags: csv, awk

I wrote the following code:

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     NR==FNR && 
     $7{sum+=$7; 
     elementos++; 
     next}
     !$7{$7=media}
     {print}
     ENDFILE{media=sum/elementos}
```

This `awk` script adds the average age to the empty cells on column 'age'.

Execution of the code is done as follows:

```
awk -f c_awk.awk train3.csv
```

Now I am trying to save the changes done in a new CSV file using `awk`. (new file: train4.csv)

I have been trying with
`> ./c_awk.awk/train4.csv` in the last line but it doesn't work.

```
awk: c_awk.awk:12:      ENDFILE{media=sum/elementos}> /tmp/train4.csv
awk: c_awk.awk:12:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: c_awk.awk:12:      ENDFILE{media=sum/elementos}> /tmp/train4.csv
awk: c_awk.awk:12:                                               ^ syntax error
```

The file from where I am trying to implement the changes looks like this:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
```

The expected result is the following:

```
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
```

Thanks.

Comment: You asked how to redirect the output of an awk script to a file and we showed you how to do that. If your awk script doesn't produce the output you want and you also need help getting your awk script to produce that output then ask a new question - only ask 1 question at a time so others in future with similar problems can search the archives to find answers. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -f c_awk.awk train3.csv > /tmp/train4.csv
```

or just change `{print}` to `{print > "/tmp/train4.csv"}`

Your script contains several issues unrelated to writing to a new file that I suspect you aren't aware of - you should post a new question with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you with that as it's not entirely clear what you want that script to do

Comment: sorry, you're right. I added some lines of the dataset. I am triying to save as a new csv file in the script awk and not while executing it. I guess it is also possible, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible and I just updated my question to show that. You added input but not the expected output - please create a new question but this time show both sample input and the expected output given that input as your script does have several issues that should be addressed but they're nothing to do with this question that you asked of how to write the output to a file.

Comment: thanks. I got the lines of the resulting output code, do you mean I should also include it here? I thought this wasn't necessary for this specific question.

Comment: I'll add the expected result as the code still doesn't solve the question I had.

Comment: It definitely DOES solve the question you asked. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: The question was about adding the option of saving in a new CSV file the changes done on the original one. Since I execute the code and it doesn't create a new CSV File, I think it doesn't.

Comment: My answer redirects your output to a new file. If your script produces output it WILL be redirected to that new file. If your script doesn't produce any output then there won't be anything in that new file (and with the 2nd approach the new file won't even be created) but that would be part of why you need to ask a new question to correct your script, it has nothing to do with the question you asked here of how to redirect the output of an awk script to a file.

Comment: my code executes producing an output but the file does not appear. Where is going to be saved the output CSV file? In te current directory I am working? Not in this case.

Comment: The output will be saved in a CSV named whatever you say the file should be named in whatever directory path you specify. If you specify that the output should go to `/tmp/train4.csv` as you show in the code in your question, and so I'm using in the code in my answer, then the output will appear in the file `train4.csv` in the directory `/tmp` exactly as you told it to.

Comment: now I got it. I need to set the current directory. Is it with  `pwd`  again?  ```{print > "/`pwd`/train4.csv"} ```

Comment: No, if you want to print to a file in the directory you're running the script from it's just `print > "train4.csv"`, see my comment in your previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433149/removing-csv-files-once-they-are-used-using-bash#comment124509838_70433235. Regarding your suggestion of ```{print > "/`pwd`/train4.csv"}``` though - **awk is not shell**, you can't use shell constructs like ticks to execute commands or even directly call Unix commands like `pwd` from awk any more than you could from a `C` program.